# jqGrid: edit form in the subgrid area accordion

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

We are using Jqgrid but we need to perform a custom editing. 
In particular we want to view/edit the detail of a row **inside the accordion of a subgrid area** (instead of real subgrid)... 
Basically we are looking for a way to redirect the content of the edit popup to the subgrid area.
Anyone have some ideas about how to do it?

Peter

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correct the problem you may look at [this demo](http://www.guriddo.net/demo/guriddojs/hierarchy/custom_row_details/index.html) in case you use Guriddo jqGrid JavaScript. In your case the html file can contain template form, where you can get the values from the row and put it in the form.

If you have difficulties we can prepare a online demo.